# Does jQuery's delay() work with replaceWith()?

Tags: jquery

Is there anything wrong with this jQuery? The delay doesn't seems to work.

```
 $( "#checked_value" ).replaceWith( "<div id='checked_value_loading'></div>").slideUp( 300 ).delay( 8000 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

When I add in `alert("test");` before the line of code, I can see it change to `<div id='checked_value_loading'></div>`, but without the alert, there is no delay...

Comment: `replaceWith` does not use the queue, so is unaffected by `delay()`. What effect are you trying to get with this element?

Comment: You'll have to use `setTimeout` here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) returns the *original* set of elements, not the new one, so you are applying effects to elements that are not part of the DOM anymore.

A simple solution is to reverse your logic and use [replaceAll()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/) instead:

```
$("<div id='checked_value_loading'></div>")
    .replaceAll("#checked_value")
    .slideUp(300).delay(8000).fadeIn(400);
```